# Error cannot find symbol org.apache.cordova.CordovaHttpAuthHandler using InAppBrowser Cordova 5.3.3

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am developing a hybrid mobile app using `cordova` and`Multi-Device hybrid app`,
I get this error when I try to run the build the app for device or emulator

```
[javac] C:\phonegap\projects\JarChee\Mobile\JarCheeMobileApp\JarChee\bld\Debug\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
[javac] import org.apache.cordova.CordovaHttpAuthHandler;
[javac]                          ^
[javac]   symbol:   class CordovaHttpAuthHandler
[javac]   location: package org.apache.cordova
[javac] C:\phonegap\projects\JarChee\Mobile\JarCheeMobileApp\JarChee\bld\Debug\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\inappbrowser\InAppBrowser.java:896: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]             if (pluginManager != null && pluginManager.onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(webView, new CordovaHttpAuthHandler(handler), host, realm)) {
[javac]                                                                                               ^
[javac]   symbol:   class CordovaHttpAuthHandler
[javac]   location: class InAppBrowser.InAppBrowserClient
```

inappbrowser version is `1.1.2-dev`

p.s I found this commit on InAppBrowser github https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/82/files?diff=split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and writing the answer here in case of somebody has the same problem

The root of the problem was the version on Cordova, it seems that this error exists on < v4, but I was using 5.3.3 how this is possible
When you `clear cordova cache` from visual studio menu, it replace v4.0.0 into the directories, so you need to copy the cordova again from `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\cordova` to `%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\node_modules\cordova`